# Passing arguments to ModelForm through FormSet

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm kinda new to Formsets and I'm stuck at a problem.

I use a Modelform to allow the creation of a new object.

```
class AddUpdateEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Zeit
        exclude = ('mitarbeiter', 'user_updated')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(AddUpdateEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['projekt'].queryset = Projekt.objects.filter(firma=Mitarbeiter.objects.get(user_id=self.user).firma_id)
```

That form gets it's arguments from the view:

```
form = AddUpdateEntryForm(user=entry_user, initial=initial)
```

Now, I want to display multiple instances of that form on a single page.
I use:

```
forms.py:
AddEntryFormSet = formset_factory(form=AddUpdateEntryForm)
```

and

```
views.py:
formset = AddEntryFormSet(initial=initial)
```

which works fine, but only when I comment out the "self.user...." and "self.fields...." lines from ModelForm Class.

I tried several ways of passing the argument from the call inside the view to the ModelForm. 
Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance
Conrad

Comment: If you're using model forms, then I recommend using `modelformset_factory` instead of `formset_factory`, so that you get the benefits of [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Comment: I first tried modelformset_factory, but it makes no differnce when you use a custom ModelForm. The advantage is of modelformset_factory when you want to have a ModelFormSet without using an existing ModelForm.

Comment: There is a difference, even when you use a custom model form. A model formset created by `modelformset_factory` can be instantiated with a queryset, and will have a `save()` method, unlike a formset created by `formset_factory`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible to subclass [`BaseModelFormset`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/forms/models.py#L524) so that the user is passed to each form when it is constructed. However, that's quite tricky.

A simpler technique is to define a function that creates a model form for a given user, and dynamically create the model form class in the view.

```
def create_form(user):
    """Returns a new model form which uses the correct queryset for user"""

    class AddUpdateEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Zeit
            exclude = ('mitarbeiter', 'user_updated')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AddUpdateEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['projekt'].queryset = Projekt.objects.filter(firma=Mitarbeiter.objects.get(user_id=user).firma_id)

    return AddUpdateEntryForm
```

The closure of `user` in the function means that you can set the queryset correctly. Note that the `__init__` method takes the same arguments as its parent class, so we no longer have any problems when we use `modelformset_factory` in the view.

```
AddUpdateEntryForm = create_form(user)
AddEntryFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Zeit, form=AddUpdateEntryForm)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I have the class inside the function, it can't be found.
global name 'AddUpdateEntryForm' is not defined

Comment: I had missed out the `return` statement from the function. If you add it then it should work.

Comment: Same problem, global name 'AddUpdateEntryForm' is not defined.

Comment: There was another typo. I had `AddEntryForm` instead of `AddUpdateEntryForm`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. Shame on me, that I didn't see it myself. I was a bit surprised that Django has no built-in functionality for that case. But anyway, it works with this more Python specific approach.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair for this answer.  Ran into the same issue and after combing the docs, I was also surprised there wasn't a built-in way of doing this.  Maybe Django 5.0.